# Why is logic for first (and only) first item of an array duplicated when running method in another Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a button in a windows application which creates a new instance from a Thread and start invoking a method, that methods get some files and insert their contents into a database.
The problem is that I always notice that the first file is inserted twice into the db, but it works fine with the other files although all of them are in the same loop.

```
private Thread thrd;
thrd = new Thread(FetchNewMessages);
_status = true;
thrd.Start();

private void FetchNewMessages()
{
    try
    {
        WriteUiLog("Start fetching messages...");
        while (_status)
        {
            try
            {
                var dir = new DirectoryInfo(txtQueue.Text);
                var allFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                if (allFiles.Length == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach (var fil in allFiles)
                {
                    if (_status)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // insert into db
                        }
                        catch (Exception iEx)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever set _status to false? What will happen if you click the button twice, thrice, etc?

Comment: It is not readily apparent from the code-excerpt that you have posted where the error might be. *This* code desk-checks fine to me. But you said that this app was *multi-threaded?* As a quick first-blush check, try limiting it to *one* thread and see what happens.

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev I always click it once, and what do you think about making _status = false?

Comment: @MikeRobinson I made it run in one single thread and regardless the main app's thread and I got the same, or do you suggest to leave it run on the main app's thread only?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie yes it is a TextBox and I read its Text property from the continuous loop in a background thread, Is there a problem with that?

Comment: The value of `txtQueue.Text` can change while your `FetchNewMessages` is processing the background.  It could conceivably have a different value each time through the `while` loop.  Ultimately I think the issue is not in the logic/code which you've shared, however.  What are you using for the DB work?  ADO.NET or some ORM?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie the Textbox is disabled and no user has a control on it, so its value couldn't be changed and I'm using ADO.NET for my db work.
Thank you

Comment: I don't know how many threads you have, and I don't really want to get too far into it, but if you *did* have more than one, my suggestion (probably useless) was to reduce it to just one child thread.  But, based on further comments made here, my comment probably *was* useless. **:*)**

Comment: I tried on 2010 and 2015 but i got the same, but you will be wondered when you know that if I traced the code by breaking point it I didn't get that issue absolutely :) .. and if I let the app do it by itself without debugging the issue doesn't always occurred. Don't ask me how .. don't ask me why :)

Comment: One thing is that `_status` is never set to false in your code snippet, so your `while` loop is infinite.  You shouldn't be getting 1-or-2 copies of your first file, and 1 of the rest.  Rather, you should be getting many, many, many copies of all files, until you terminate the program.

Comment: Look dude, the scenario as following: I have a shared folder which is updated from time to time and my application should be in infinite loop to check all of new files which are added to this folder, then I get all of files and go into another loop (foreach) and insert each file's content into the db then move the file into another place looks like an archive folder. So, the infinite while loop is mandatory to being ready to catch the new files on time and insert the contents into the db. And the weird issue here is why I get it in the first file only?

Comment: The _status variable here is when the users wants to close the application anytime without losing any data if the cursor was in the loop, so that variable makes the app doesn't accept closing suddenly unless the user clicked on a Stop button to ask the internal loop stops without losing data .. I hope you get it

Comment: Infinite loop is fine, but there are a lot of assumptions open given the block of code you've posted.  Where is the cleanup logic for the files?  Is it done in such a way that you are sure the files are cleaned up before going back into the loop?  Does the code ever enter your `catch` blocks?  It could be that the first file is sometimes not closed before the cleanup, thus not removed from disc, thus picked up again the second loop.  Lots of things could be going on.

Comment: The code doesn't enter the exception block and your thinking about cleanup may be true but why specially the first file only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120170/discussion-between-mike-guthrie-and-ahmed-negm).